# Html from url using async, Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

Hi I'm pretty new to android dev however I have searched these forums and found nothing conclusive. I am trying to display HTML from a site in a text view using ASyncTask. Here is the code I'm using below.

```
package com.uad1001.theredux;
//imports    
public class Htmlfromurl extends Activity {
    Button btnSend;
    EditText PhoneNo; 
    TextView t  = new TextView(this);
    String html;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_htmlfromurl);
        t =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.IPDisplay);
        // will implement later
            //PhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone);
        //btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send); 
        String IPurl = "http://myexternalip.com/raw"; //URL I want to scrape

        new event().execute(IPurl);
    }

    public class event extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String...url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String urls = url[0];
            try 
            {
                Thread.sleep(4000);
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(urls);
                ResponseHandler<String> resHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                String page = httpClient.execute(httpGet, resHandler);
                return page;
            }
            catch (ClientProtocolException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Error";
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Error";
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Error";
            }   

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String page){

            t.setText(page);
        }   
    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.htmlfromurl, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

The program crashes instantly. The logcat shows:
(also at http://pastebin.com/3sTENx2q)

```
08-05 19:38:54.082: W/dalvikvm(11472): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x410942a0)
08-05 19:38:54.092: E/AndroidRuntime(11472): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-05 19:38:54.092: E/AndroidRuntime(11472): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.uad1001.theredux/com.uad1001.theredux.Htmlfromurl}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-05 19:38:54.092: E/AndroidRuntime(11472):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2016)
08-05 19:38:54.092: E/AndroidRuntime(11472):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
08-05 19:38:54.092: E/AndroidRuntime(11472):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
08-05 19:38:54.092: E/AndroidRuntime(11472):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
08-05 19:38:54.092: E/AndroidRuntime(11472):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-05 19:38:54.092: E/AndroidRuntime(11472):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-05 19:38:54.092: E/AndroidRuntime(11472):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
08-05 19:38:54.092: E/AndroidRuntime(11472):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 19:38:54.092: E/AndroidRuntime(11472):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-05 19:38:54.092: E/AndroidRuntime(11472):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
08-05 19:38:54.092: E/AndroidRuntime(11472):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
08-05 19:38:54.092: E/AndroidRuntime(11472):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-05 19:38:54.092: E/AndroidRuntime(11472): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-05 19:38:54.092: E/AndroidRuntime(11472):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:81)
08-05 19:38:54.092: E/AndroidRuntime(11472):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3296)
08-05 19:38:54.092: E/AndroidRuntime(11472):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3364)
08-05 19:38:54.092: E/AndroidRuntime(11472):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:584)
08-05 19:38:54.092: E/AndroidRuntime(11472):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:579)
08-05 19:38:54.092: E/AndroidRuntime(11472):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:575)
08-05 19:38:54.092: E/AndroidRuntime(11472):    at com.uad1001.theredux.Htmlfromurl.<init>(Htmlfromurl.java:23)
08-05 19:38:54.092: E/AndroidRuntime(11472):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
08-05 19:38:54.092: E/AndroidRuntime(11472):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
08-05 19:38:54.092: E/AndroidRuntime(11472):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
08-05 19:38:54.092: E/AndroidRuntime(11472):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2007)
08-05 19:38:54.092: E/AndroidRuntime(11472):    ... 11 more
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your logcat shows a null pointer on line 23. Which line is that?

Comment: The 23rd line is 

TextView t  = new TextView(this);

Sweet fixed the issue thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your error is being caused by the `TextView t = new TextView(this);`. I don't think you want to be instantiating it like that. Instead just leave it as `TextView t;` in your instance variable and instantiate it by finding it by ID in your `onCreate` method as you are doing. That should solve the problem. The `TextView` constructor is supposed to take a Context, which is more an abstract object, so instantiating it using the constructor is generally best to not do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use my [droidQuery](http://phil-brown.github.io/droidQuery/) library to handle most of the grunt-work for you:

```
public void includeHTML(TextView t, String url) {

    $.ajax(new AjaxOptions().url("http://myexternalip.com/raw")
                            .type("get")
                            .dataType("html")
                            .context(this)
                            .success(new Function() {
                                @Override
                                public void invoke($ droidQuery, Object... params) {
                                    $.with(t).html((String) params[0]);
                                }
                            })
                            .error(new Function() {
                                @Override
                                public void invoke($ droidQuery, Object... params) {
                                    AjaxError error = (AjaxError) params[0];
                                    Log.e("$", "Error " + error.status + ": " + error.error);
                                }
                            }));
}
```

Then you just call:

```
includeHTML(t, url);
```

If you want a 4 second delay, you can use:

```
$.setTimeout(new Function() {
    @Override
    public void invoke($ droidQuery, Object... params) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            includeHTML(t, url);
        });
    }
}, 4000);
```